# Find & Replace elements in array of hashes - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes as below

```
status_arr = [{id: 5, status: false}, 
              {id: 7, status: false}, 
              {id: 3, status: false},
              {id: 9, status: false} ]
```

I would like to update the hash with status: true if it has ids 5, 7

```
update_ids = [5, 9]
```

I am trying the following and has no idea to proceed

```
status_arr.select{ |arr| update_ids.include?(arr[:id]) arr[:status] = true}
```

Expected output:

```
status_arr = [{id: 5, status: true}, 
              {id: 7, status: false}, 
              {id: 3, status: false},
              {id: 9, status: true} ]
```

Comment: You are actually very close you could just change this `status_arr.select{ |arr| update_ids.include?(arr[:id]) arr[:status] = true}` to `status_arr.select{ |arr| update_ids.include?(arr[:id])}.each{|arr| arr[:status] = true}` or `status_arr.each{ |arr| arr[:status] = update_ids.include?(arr[:id]) }`

Comment: You can do this. `status_arr.select{ |arr| arr[:status] = true if update_ids.include?(arr[:id])}`

Comment: `status_arr.map { |h| h.merge(status: [5,9].include?(h[:id])) }`

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'set'
update_ids = Set.new([5,3])
status_arr.map{ |s| s[:status] = update_ids.include?(s[:id]); s }
#=> [{:id=>5, :status=>true}, {:id=>7, :status=>false}, {:id=>3, :status=>true}, {:id=>9, :status=>false}]
```

instead of `Set` you can use just a `Hash`

```
update_ids = {5 => true, 3=> true}
status_arr.map{ |s| s[:status] = update_ids.include?(s[:id]); s }
#=> [{:id=>5, :status=>true}, {:id=>7, :status=>false}, {:id=>3, :status=>true}, {:id=>9, :status=>false}]
```

Or an array, but it will have some performance issues for big arrays

```
update_ids = [5,3]
status_arr.map{ |s| s[:status] = update_ids.include?(s[:id]); s }
#=> [{:id=>5, :status=>true}, {:id=>7, :status=>false}, {:id=>3, :status=>true}, {:id=>9, :status=>false}]
```